# Windows 10 hangs on startup and taskbar on wrong monitor

Tags: windows-10, boot, multiple-monitors, freeze, taskbar

Since I have my new hardware in my PC, I have a problem starting my computer. When it is off for several hours and I boot my pc windows hangs up at the login screen and shows me a black picture on my monitors. When I then reset the PC it loads windows normally and sometimes it is so that the primary taskbar is displayed on the secondary monitor.
I have already tried a few things.

1. primary monitor is stored as primary monitor in the windows display settings.
2. i updated all system devices in the device manager and also updated
   my graphics card.
3. i completely reinstalled windows (reinstalled windows and kept private data)
4. check the monitors in the BIOS. I could not detect any abnormalities.

My setup:

- **Monitors:** 1x 4k monitor (primary/display port/extended), 2x HD monitors (secondary/HDMI/extended) The 4k monitor and one  HDMI monitor are cloned.
- **Graphics card:** NVIDIA GTX 970
- **Motherboard:** Asus Prime B350 plus
- **CPU:** AMD Ryzen 5 2600X Six-Core
- **Hard disks:** 1x SSD (Windows), 1x HDD (Data) The Windows folders Desktop, Documents, Downloads, Pictures are on the HDD

I hope someone still has some ideas how I can solve the problem, because resetting your computer at every start is not only time consuming but also not too good for the computer.

If you need any more information, I will be pleased to provide it.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I solved the problem. I burned a Windows 10 Iso onto a DVD and started the Windows 10 installation from the DVD. During the installation I completely deleted all partitions, including the private data, and reinstalled Windows 10. Now my system boots normally again since 2 days.